# How to correctly use Meteor spiderable on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, heroku, meteor

I use [spiderable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable) package for web search engines. This provides return correct page for search bot.

- Phantomjs  is installed on the server.
- I used [this](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) buildpack
  for meteor.

Search bots visit the site and request urls `<site>?_escaped_fragment_=`. By default meteor returns a page with an empty body. With spiderable meteor should return a normal page with actual content in the body.

In development everything works fine. But in heroku meteor returns empty body. I have no errors in server logs.

I dont understand which part is not working: phantomjs or buildpack or spiderable?

What is the correct way to use spiderable on Heroku?